# (..).then is not a function ,firebase cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to run a function asynchronously.But it throws error. Below is my code:

```
exports.listenForNotificationRequests = functions.database.ref('/notificationRequests/{pushId}')
    .onWrite(event => {
       const requestId = event.data.val();
       var sentTo = requestId.sentTo;
       var senderIds =  sentTo.split(",");
     //  var senderTokens = "";

       var payload = {
                data: {
                  title: requestId.username,
                  message:  requestId.message,
                  sentFrom: requestId.sentFrom
                }
        };

       getSenderIds(senderIds).then(function(senderTokens){
            console.log("SenderTokens", senderTokens);
            admin.messaging().sendToDevice(senderTokens.split(","), payload)
                    .then(function(response) {
                      console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                      console.log("Error sending message:", error);
            });

       });

});

function getSenderIds(senderIds){
    var senderTokens = "";
    senderIds.forEach(function (snapshot){
                var ref = admin.database().ref("users/"+snapshot+"/token");
                console.log("refernce", snapshot);
                ref.once("value", function(querySnapshot2) {
                         var snapVal = querySnapshot2.val();
                         console.log("Token", snapVal);
                         senderTokens = senderTokens+","+snapVal;
                });
    });
    return senderTokens;
}
```

While on execution it throws exceprtion:

```
TypeError: getSenderIds(...).then is not a function
    at exports.listenForNotificationRequests.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:20:39)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:35:20
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)
```

I have tried multiple solutions but none of use. Can anybody here point out what  mistake I am making? Or if there is any other solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use then() your getSenderIds() should return a Promise while at the moment it returns a string.

ref.once() does return a Promise. What you could do is make senderTokens an array and for each iteration push ref.once() to this array.

Because ref.once() returns a Promise this makes senderTokens an array of Promises which will contain the result of each query. You can then return Promise.all(senderTokens) [read more about Promise.all here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Then do the to String processing inside the then (function(senderTokens){}) 
 block by calling .val() on each item of the senderTokens array.

Comment: You could also reduce the promises

Comment: Thank you, it was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can not return a function , you need to either return an event or nothing.